# How can I format a function declaration to force curly brace at the end of the line?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, formatting, filetype-php

I have big portions of code where functions are formatted with the opening curly brace on the next line, like this :

```
function foo()
{
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to search / replace in order to change it to this :

```
function foo(){
}
```

Comment: Today, most languages have tools to format code consistently and allow you to change a convention afterwards. Since you did not specify the language, I cannot point you to a tool for your language. But for example there is https://prettier.io/ which allows you to format a wide variety of languages. Integration into vim can be done via `formatprg` or use a plugin such as https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier or https://github.com/sbdchd/neoformat.

Comment: This is for Wordpress, so a mix of php and html. prettier.io seems nice, but the PHP plugin is in alpha stage and not recommended for production. I'll have a look at the other ones. In the end I'm also happy to learn vimscript by implementing my own simple solutions on a specific need basis.

Comment: I did a quick check on some of the php & html formatters: as far as I see none of them supports mixed html/php files [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3702#issuecomment-396717120), [prettier-php](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php/issues/1010). So you have to apply them manually on code parts and it cannot be fully automated. I also doubt that vim can provide any help with that except manually running substitute commands. But this is a general vim feature not specific to formatting which adds your question to the long list of how can I replace X with Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new line character is your search (`\n` for linux):

```
:%s/)\s*\n{/){/c
```

Replaces `)\s*\n{` into `){`

The `c` flag at the end will ask you to confirm before each replacement.

EDIT:
Another solution would be to use the join line feature (`J`) with the `g` command:

```
:g/function [^{]\+$/join
```

Which will execute the command `join` on every line matching the pattern `function [^{]\+$` ("function" followed by anything without a `{`).

It will however put a space by default between `)` and `{`, it can be changed by running the following *before* the g command:

```
:set nojoinspaces
```

Comment: You dont need norm J, :join is an ex command

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this one :-)

Comment: And even if you did need `norm`  you should use `norm! ` instead. I think.

Comment: @padawin thanks, I like the join solution, as it can easily be adapted to apply the formatting to Classes also.